# Can't import CSV to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

i have a problem in importing my CSV file towards my MySQL Server through PHP.
I have searched for answers, tried various codes, and addap them to my code.
The CSV file only has one column with over 500 rows of data, which are emails.
I wish to import them to my server, to the table email on the column email.
I keep getting undefined index error.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $db_user = "root"; 
    $db_password = "";
    $db = "trabalho1"; 
    $conn = mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
    echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            print_r($emapData);
            $sql = "INSERT into email(email) values('$emapData[0]')";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo "CSV File has been successfully Imported";
        header("Location:../listar/listaremail.php");
    }
    else
      echo "Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File";
}
?>
```

My form, which comes from a html page is on this format.

```
    <form id="formulario1" name="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validar(this);" action="../inserir/inseriremailexcel.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>A partir do Excel</legend>
                 <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150"> <br>                               
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <fieldset>          
                <button type="submit" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
            </fieldset></h1>
            Atenção. A data e hora actual serão gravadas com o seu registo.
    </form>
```

Any tips on the problem? I have visited various pages, and tried many fixes, but none will work.

Full error is as following
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inseriremailexcel.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inseriremailexcel.php on line 13
Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File

Comment: Post full error please?

Comment: Could it be the `["tmp_name"]` bit causing problems?

Comment: @Chrisky, i have tried removing that. And it gives the same error. I didn't use it originally, but most of the codes i saw had it included, and i took the conclusion tha it was necessary for when later on you have [size], in order to have something before it. Not sure if i explained myself correctly

Comment: Posted full error @eXplicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form.

```
<form id="formulario1" name="post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validar(this);" action="../inserir/inseriremailexcel.php">...</form>
```

Comment: Now it gave me C:\xampp\tmp\php7705.tmpArray ( [0] => marioantunes@switchconcept.com;;;;;;;;;;;;; ) Array ( [0] => amlobo@mail.telepac.pt;;;;;;;;;;;;; ) Repeated for all the emails contained. And on the last line it says Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inseriremailexcel.php:19) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inseriremailexcel.php on line 25. 
But at least it's now sending data to the database

Comment: It gives you the error "...headers already send..." because you have "echo" statements before the "header("Localtion: ")"

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need to have enctype="multipart/form-data" in the "form" tag for uploading files.

Comment: Now it gave me 
        C:\xampp\tmp\php7705.tmpArray ( [0] => marioantunes@switchconcept.com;;;;;;;;;;;;; ) Array ( [0] => amlobo@mail.telepac.pt;;;;;;;;;;;;; )

Repeated for all the emails contained.
And on the last line it says
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inseriremailexcel.php:19) in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\trabalho\inserir\inseriremailexcel.php on line 25

Comment: But, the data has passed to the database and created several rows, except that they are empty